# Косяк в делегировании

Tags: javascript

```js
var ul = document.querySelectorAll('.tree');
// console.log(ul);
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
// console.log(lis);

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
  var li = lis[i];
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  li.insertBefore(span, li.firstChild);
  span.appendChild(span.nextSibling);
}

ul.onclick = function(event){
  var target = event.target;
  var li = target.parentNode;
  var childrenContainer = document.querySelectorAll('li > ul');
  childrenContainer.classList.toggle('.s')
}
```

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

 .s{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
     <ul class="tree">
    <li>Животные
      <ul>
        <li>Млекопитающие
          <ul>
            <li>Коровы</li>
            <li>Ослы</li>
            <li>Собаки</li>
            <li>Тигры</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Другие
          <ul >
            <li>Змеи</li>
            <li>Птицы</li>
            <li>Ящерицы</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Рыбы
      <ul >
        <li>Аквариумные
          <ul>
            <li>Гуппи</li>
            <li>Скалярии</li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>Морские
          <ul >
            <li>Морская форель</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У коллекций, которые возвращаются методом `querySelectorAll`, нет свойств `onclick` и `classList`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.tree').forEach(function(el) { 
  el.onclick = function(event){
    ...
  };
});

childrenContainer.forEach(function(el) { el.classList.toggle('.s'); });
```

Comment: а что такое el и =>

Comment: Метод querySelectorAll  единственный где не работают свойства onclick и classList ?

Comment: @Leks Любой метод, который возвращает не DOM-элемент.